# OpenLDAP Multiple Directory Manager Accounts / Groups

Tags: openldap

So the documentation sucks and the interwebs hasn't produced the answers I am looking for. Hopefully somebody here has some wisdom to unleash...

I recently built an OpenLDAP server for Linux authentication and SUDO. I am using phpldapadmin with some custom templates for adding accounts, groups, sudo rules, etc... However, all these changes need to happen using the directory manager ROOTDN account.... I have not been successful with creating the proper ACLs to allow an LDAP user or group to administer the directory the same way the ROOTDN account is able to.

Comment: It's documented. You shouldn't use the RootDN account for anything. That's for OpenLDAP itself. For one thing, it bypasses all the overlays.

Comment: Welcome  and thank you for posting your first question on ServerFault. Getting good answers requires the effort of [writing a good question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and as it stands now yours is missing sufficient detail to provide you with a good solution. Please show what you have attempted so far and what exactly you want to achieve.